# Determining symbolic path

Tags: perl

I have been using Cwd 'abs_path' to get the exact location of our script containing shared parameter values and functions so that they are interchangeable across our dev/qa/uat/prod environments.

Code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $script_path = abs_path($0);
my @folders = split(/\//,$script_path);
my $env = $folders[3];
my $file_loc "/prod/ops/$env/env_shared/ulvr_env.pl";
print "$0\n";
print "$script_path\n";
print "$env\n";
print "file location:  $file_loc\n";
```

$env would resolve to 'dev', 'qa', 'uat', or 'prod' depending on the directory that the script is in.  This code has worked well for us until now.  Our production server still has the absolute path '/prod' but due to space constraints, we have moved our scripts from '/prod' to '/data/prod' with a symlink.

Results:

```
$ ./test_path.pl
/prod/ops/prod/test_path.pl
prod
file location:  /prod/ops/prod/env_shared/ulvr_env.pl
```

As you can see, it returns the absolute path (as it should) so I need to know how I can universally determine which path to use for the ulvr_env.pl depending on if the script is running in prod, dev, qa, or uat.  this (these) scripts need to work the same whether the full path is used for executing or relative path is used.  I have tried using:

```
use File::Spec;
my $script_path = File::Spec->rel2abs( $0) ;
```

which works when the script is run specifying the full symbolic path but it does not work when attempting to run from cwd

```
$ /prod/ops/qa/test_path.pl
/prod/ops/qa/test_path.pl
ops
file location:  /prod/ops/qa/env_shared/ulvr_env.pl

$ ./test_path.pl
/data/prod/ops/qa/test_path.pl
ops
file location:  /prod/ops/ops/env_shared/ulvr_env.pl
```

What would be the best way to get it to return the "qa", "uat", or "prod" without having to maintain different code for each location?

Comment: I don't quite get the problem: is it that after `/prod` became `/data/prod` you are now getting `ops` instead of `prod|qa|...` (etc)?  That should be solved by changing `$folders[3]` to `$folders[4]`, no?  (But, much better, use `File::Spec` to parse paths!).

Comment: you are correct that the issue is getting ops instead of qa|dev|uat.  on one server we have /data/prod/ops/<env>/ on the production server we have /prod/ops/prod.  So changing $folders[3] to $folders[4] would solve for /data/prod/ops/<env> but then it would return the wrong value on the production server:
/data/prod/ops/qa/tools  = qa
/prod/ops/prod/tools = tools  <- should be prod

Comment: Ah, the paths are actually _different_ on different machines? Then the script should establish this in the beginning and set things up. It can check what machine it runs on and have hard-coded rules (paths) for each, or bluntly check whether paths are with `/data/...` or without it.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, but it does solve the problem with portability of code:

```
use File::Spec;

my $script_path = File::Spec->rel2abs( $0) ;
print "script path: $script_path\n";
$script_path =~ s/^\/data//; # replace /data at beginning of string with nothing
my @folders = split(/\//,$script_path);
my $curr_env = $folders[3];
print "$curr_env\n";
my $file_loc = "/prod/ops/$curr_env/env_shared/ulvr_env.pl";

print "file location:  $file_loc\n";
```

QA Server Output:

```
$ ./test_path.pl
script path: /data/prod/ops/qa/test_path.pl
qa
file location:  /prod/ops/qa/env_shared/ulvr_env.pl
```

PROD Server Output:

```
$ ./test_path.pl
script path: /prod/ops/prod/test_path.pl
prod
file location:  /prod/ops/prod/env_shared/ulvr_env.pl
```

Comment: Yes, that'd be one way to deal with it.  I suggest to use the core `File::Spec` to split a path into directories (or some other well established module).